# Rails collecting and rendering JSON data in to a Highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, highcharts

I am trying to pass labels in to a Highcharts column chart on the x axis.

Currently the chart works in that it renders the data but the x axis labels show 0,1,2,3...etc which is the default when there is nothing to render.

notes_controller:

```
def dashboard
  @data = Note.getData()
end
```

note.rb

```
def self.getData
    data = []
    self.subject_types.each do |type|
      data << self.type_count(type)
    end
    data
  end

private

  def self.subject_types
    pluck(:subject_type).uniq
  end

  def self.type_count(type)
    where(subject_type: type).count
  end
end
```

dashboard.html.erb javascript

```
...series: [{
           name: 'Number of Notes By Class Module',
           data: <%= @data %>
          }]...
```

The above works which is great but how do I get the labels to show? They should be coming from a column called subject_type from my table. I have tried the following:

note.rb:

```
def self.getSubjects
    respond_to do |format|
    render :json => @note.to_json(:only => [:subject_type])
end
```

(I'm probably doing this totally wrong!)

notes_controller.rb:

```
def subject
    @subject = Note.getSubjects()
end
```

dashboard.html.erb:

```
...series: [{
               name: 'Number of Notes By Class Module',
               data: <%= @data %>, <%= @subject %>
              }]...
```

Thanks. Any help here i'd really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to print `subject_type` in `x-axis` ? The `axes` of charts are generally used for measurement. An axis can be either, linear, logarithmic, datetime or categories.

As per my understanding, you want to show each `subject_type` as a `series name`.

If `No` try this

```
xAxis: {
    categories: '<%=raw @subjects.to_json %>'
}
```

If `Yes` try this

[Highcharts series](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series)   object is an array, meaning it can contain several series. The `name` attribute gives the series a name. The `data` attribute represent the series values.

It means our `series` must be something like this.

```
series: [ 
          {name: 'Subject Type 1', data: [5] }, 
          {name: 'Subject Type 2', data: [6] }, 
          {name: 'Subject Type n', data: [n] }, 
        ]
```

You have a `Note` table which has `subject_type` column. Each `note` must contain a `subject_type`. You just need to find out the uniq `subject_type` that become the `name` of the `series` and total count of that `subject_type` that become the `data` of the `series`.

You can get it by doing:

```
def dashboard
  @series_data = []
  @notes = Note.select("id, subject_type, COUNT(*) AS total").group("id, subject_type")
  # Collect series data that will be show
  @notes.group_by(&:subject_type).each do |k, v|
    @series_data << { name: k.titleize, data: [v.size] }   
  end
end
```

In your **dashboard.html.erb**

```
series: <%=raw @series_data.to_json %>
```

As I can see above, you also need chart `title`. You can do it in this way.

```
title: {
  text: "<strong>Number of Notes By Class Module</strong>"
}
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, we will use your current class method to get an array of `subject_types`:

```
def dashboard
  @data = Note.getData()
  @subjects = Note.subject_types
end
```

Then following Highchats [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels), the `xAxis: categories` json key is where we need to put the `subjects` array of labels:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },

  //other options ...

  xAxis: {
    categories: <%= @subjects %>
  },

  series: [{
     name: 'Number of Notes By Class Module',
     data: <%= @data %>
  }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work. I can tell it's nearly there. Maybe it has to go in the data: part somehow?